# select2 not removing default 0 value when another selection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, jquery-select2

When I select value in select2 multiple selection, the default 0 value is still there in the list.
Any ideas how to remove it?

[image]

```
div class="row mg-t-20">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ActivityThatIsAssigned, new { @class = "col-sm-4 form-control-label" })
                        <div class="col-sm-8 mg-t-10 mg-sm-t-0">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ActivityThatIsAassignedId, Model.ActivityThatIsAssigned, new { @class = "dropdown js-ActivityThatIsNotAssigned-dropdown", @multiple = "multiple", @style = "width: 100%;" })
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ActivityThatIsAassignedId)
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

model item

```
[Display(Name = "Activity that is assigned")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ActivityThatIsAssigned { get; set; }
```

Init select2

```
 $(".dropdown").select2({ width: '100%' });

    $(".js-selectlinkedinprofile, .js-selectbatch, .js-selecttag, .js-selectfanactivity, .js-selectfandeliveryaction, .js-ConnectedToOtherProfiles").prepend('<option value="0"></option>');

    $(".dropdown.js-selectfandeliveryaction, .dropdown.js-selectlinkedinprofile, .dropdown.js-selectbatch, .dropdown.js-selecttag, .dropdown.js-selectfanactivity, .dropdown.js-selectfandeliveryaction, .dropdown.js-ActivityThatIsAssigned-dropdown, .dropdown.js-ActivityThatIsNotAssigned-dropdown, .dropdown.js-ConnectedToOtherProfiles" ).select2();

    $(".js-selectlinkedinprofile, .js-selectbatch, .js-selecttag, .js-selectfandeliveryaction,.js-ConnectedToOtherProfiles").val("0").trigger("change.select2");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just remove it by yourself on the server side (controller).

Loop ActivityThatIsAssignedId list, if equals to zero just remove it from the list.

Answer (score 0):

You must remove the hidden input in your html. Remove this line:

`@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ActivityThatIsAassignedId)`

Also:

- Make sure that the default `SelectListItem` value is set to `""` or
  `null` in your `Model.ActivityThatIsAssigned` collection.
- Make sure that `ActivityThatIsAassignedId` is nullable. (e.g. `int?`)